# How to create a login form with Angular and Polymer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, polymer-1.0

I have worked with the polymer starter kit and integrated angular. I created a route for login and home. I built a custom login element that contains a form with username, password and submit button. Where I am having trouble is figuring out how to get the ng-submit directive to know when the submit button is triggered.

What I ended up doing is removing the the ng-app directive from the html tag. In the web components script

```
        window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
            console.log('components ready');
            angular.bootstrap(document, 'app');
        });
```

the ng-submit is on the implementation of the custom element not in the template.

```
<login-form ng-submit="myfunction()"></login-form>
```

I think this holds off on initializing angular until all the Web Components are ready. I don't know though if this will work for additional views with components. If we can add directives to additional web components. I've googled around trying to find examples where directives are used with custom components.

Many other ways we can integrate these technologies. We don't have to make the entire form one component.